# C# Azure Management REST API - Bind Certificate to App Service Custom Domain

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-web-app-service, azure-custom-domain

I can create a custom domain using the Azure Management REST API, and I can create an App Service Managed certificate, which is associated with the custom domain (I think). Maybe not. However, under custom domains in my app service, it shows that I need to add a binding.

[image]

Here is the certificate:

[image]

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxx-xxx-479a-bb9f-4c7e01d9a379/resourceGroups/MyResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/xxx20211028195113/hostNameBindings/my.site?api-version=2016-08-01

and 

https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxx-xxx-479a-bb9f-4c7e01d9a379/resourceGroups/MyResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Web/certificates/my.site?api-version=2021-02-01
```

I used the first end-point to create the custom domain, and the second end-point to create the certificate. I'm not sure how to bind the certificate to the custom domain. I expected the call to create certificate to do that for me since I included the serverFarm in the request body, but it didn't work.

I want to use the Azure Management API to bind the certificate to the custom domain. How can I do that? which endpoint should I use and what values need to be set in the request body?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

For my full code reference, see my other post here:
[C# .Net Azure Management REST API - Add App Service Managed Certificate - Response = Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70809815/c-sharp-net-azure-management-rest-api-add-app-service-managed-certificate-r)

**EDIT: Showing the Complete Answer**

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyShoppingCart.Helpers.ManagementLibrarySample
{
    public class ManagementLibrarySample
    {

        static string _ClientId = Startup.StaticConfig.GetValue<string>("Azure:ClientId");
        static string _ClientKey = Startup.StaticConfig.GetValue<string>("Azure:ClientSecret");
        static string _TenantId = Startup.StaticConfig.GetValue<string>("Azure:TenantId");
        static string _SubscriptionId = Startup.StaticConfig.GetValue<string>("Azure:SubscriptionId");
        static string _ResourceGroupName = Startup.StaticConfig.GetValue<string>("Azure:ResourceGroupName");
        static string _AlternateResourceGroupName = Startup.StaticConfig.GetValue<string>("Azure:AlternateResourceGroupName");
        static string _AppName = Startup.StaticConfig.GetValue<string>("Azure:AppName");
        static string _AppServicePlanName = Startup.StaticConfig.GetValue<string>("Azure:AppServicePlanName");
        static Uri _baseURI = new Uri($"https://management.azure.com/");

        private static string GetAccessToken()
        {
            var context = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/" + _TenantId);
            ClientCredential clientCredential = new ClientCredential(_ClientId, _ClientKey);
            var tokenResponse = context.AcquireTokenAsync(_baseURI.ToString(), clientCredential).Result;
            return tokenResponse.AccessToken;
        }

        public static async Task<bool> CreateCustomDomainAndCertificate(string sHostName)
        {
            bool ret = false;

            HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await CreateCustomDomain(sHostName);

            if (responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                responseMessage = await CreateAppManagedCertificate(sHostName);

                /*
                     it can take a good 5 minutes to create the certificate
                     but you get the 202 status code right away.
                     
                     You cannot bind the certificate to the custom domain
                     name until after the certificate actually exists.
                 */

                if ((long)responseMessage.StatusCode == 202)// Accepted
                {
                    DateTime dtStart = DateTime.Now;

                    while ((long)responseMessage.StatusCode != 200 && DateTime.Now < dtStart.AddMinutes(10))
                    {//Wait until the certificate has been created, up to 10 minutes
                        Thread.Sleep(60000);//1 minute
                        responseMessage = await BindCertificateToCustomDomain(sHostName);
                    }
                    if ((long)responseMessage.StatusCode == 200)
                        ret = true;
                }
            }
            return ret;
        }

        private static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> CreateCustomDomain(string sHostName)
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + GetAccessToken());
                string requestURl = _baseURI + $"subscriptions/{_SubscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{_ResourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{_AppName}/hostNameBindings/{sHostName}?api-version=2016-08-01";
                string body = $"{{\"properties\": {{\"azureResourceName\": \"{_AppName}\"}}}}";

                var stringContent = new StringContent(body, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                return await client.PutAsync(requestURl, stringContent);
            }
        }

        private static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> CreateAppManagedCertificate(string sHostName)
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + GetAccessToken());
                string requestURl = _baseURI + $"subscriptions/{_SubscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{_ResourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Web/certificates/{sHostName}?api-version=2021-02-01";
                string serverFarm = $"/subscriptions/{_SubscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{_AlternateResourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/{_AppServicePlanName}";
                string body = $"{{\"location\": \"West US\", \"properties\": {{\"canonicalName\": \"{sHostName}\", \"hostNames\": [\"{sHostName}\"], \"serverFarmId\": \"{serverFarm}\"}}}}";

                var stringContent = new StringContent(body, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                return await client.PutAsync(requestURl, stringContent);
            }

        }

        private static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> BindCertificateToCustomDomain(string sHostName)
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + GetAccessToken());
                string requestURl = _baseURI + $"subscriptions/{_SubscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{_ResourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{_AppName}?api-version=2016-08-01";
                string serverFarm = $"/subscriptions/{_SubscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{_AlternateResourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/{_AppServicePlanName}";
                string body = $"{{\"location\": \"West US\", \"properties\": {{\"HostNameSslStates\": [ {{ \"SslState\" : \"1\", \"ToUpdate\" : \"True\", \"Name\": \"{sHostName}\"}}]}}, \"kind\": \"app\", \"location\": \"West US\", \"tags\" : {{\"hidden-related:{serverFarm}\": \"empty\"}}}}";

                var stringContent = new StringContent(body, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                return await client.PutAsync(requestURl, stringContent);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello @David.Warwick, Could you please let us know In which tier your web app placed.

Comment: When you say Tier, do you mean (B1: 1)?

Comment: Yes, App service plan .

Comment: Ok yes, that's the one I am on.

Comment: Could you please refer this MS DOC:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate#create-a-free-managed-certificate

Comment: I checked that site, but I want to use the Management API. I can create a custom domain with the API, and I can create the certificate with the API, but the custom domain is not secured by the certificate. How can I use the Management API to secure the custom domain with the app service managed certificate?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241321/discussion-between-ajaykumarghose-mt-and-david-warwick).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I use the Management API to secure the custom domain with the
> app service managed certificate?
> Thanks @David.Warwick for the confirmation,
> As we have discussed to achieve the above requirement we have to use the below Rest API .

You can try with PUT method for binding SSL certificate with Custom domain.

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroup}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{snapshotName}?api-version={api-version}
```

For more information please refer this [***`SO THREAD`***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64240951/binding-azure-app-managed-ssl-to-custom-domains-throgh-rest-api)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will update my question to show the complete solution shortly.

Comment: Glad to of help, Yeah sure. @David.Warwick