# Set custom domain with binding for webapp in Azure C#

Tags: c#, azure, dns, binding

I am looking for the way to add custom domain with binding to the webapp in Azure.

I developed something that adds custom domain, but without binding, so its status still without binding (not secured).

Here the code:

```
var webapp = GetWebApp(request.AzureHostName);

if(webapp is null)
{
    throw new Exception("Failed to get webapp for adding custom domain, will not be done");
}

webapp.App.Update()
   .DefineHostnameBinding()
   .WithThirdPartyDomain(request.DomainName)
   .WithSubDomain(request.SubDomainName)
   .WithDnsRecordType(CustomHostNameDnsRecordType.CName)
   .Attach()
   .Apply();
```

I use Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent SDK, it is already deprecated.

Is there any option to do it with this SDK, or maybe using a new one, from Azure.ResourceManager

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What is the version of the WebApp?

Comment: What is version? How can I check it in Portal?

Comment: Version refers to the framework of the WebApp. Whether it is a Core or Framework ?

Comment: Sorry, found it in the configuration
.NET
ASP .NET v4.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the code that can be used, it is not related to client implementation, it is API.

Please, see:

[C# Azure Management REST API - Bind Certificate to App Service Custom Domain](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70815827/13969337)